# Dojo marginBox return different value

Tags: javascript, css, margin, dojo

Anyone can guide me what's the difference between
**this.marginBox** 
and 
**dojo.marginBox(this.node)**

I'm confusing with this two where they return different value.

Answer (score 0):

What are the two values you're getting back? (I haven't used dojo for a while, but I seem to remember one of them including padding and the other not?)

Comment: marginBox returning in l: t: w: h:  The weird case is that this.marginBox returning negative while the other one returning positive

Answer (score 0):

Dojo only provides a `dojo.marginBox()` method — I am not aware of Dojo providing any kind of prototype or mixin that enables a `this.marginBox` method. In other words, only `dojo.marginBox(this.node)` is correct.

It would have helped if you provided examples of what those methods are returning for you. 
I would expect:

```
var example = this.marginBox;
```

to return *undefined* in most circumstances. However if you have tried to assign to `this.marginBox` like this:

```
// Don't do this - marginBox is not a DOM property!
this.marginBox = 10;
```

then future calls to `this.marginBox` would return `10`... it might look like it is doing something, but it's got nothing to do with Dojo or CSS and will just return what you put in... not very useful!

Answer (score 0):

I would be very careful in using dojo.marginBox, I was browsing around an issue about it and I found the following:

https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/12492

unfortunately the dojo team won't fix the problem because the method `dojo.marginBox(..)` will not work for hidden nodes, quoting the ticket **"the behavior is undefined when called on hidden nodes"**.

What I did I checked the node's clientWidth / Height.